# Remove Web Part from Existing Flutter Project

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

How can I remove the web component part of a Flutter project? I have a project that when it was created was automatically created with web support. Now I am 100% certain the app won't be used for web and I just want to remove support for it. Is there a command in the terminal to help me do that?

I tried checking through the other questions but the others were asking how to disable web support altogether. I just want to remove web support on one project.

Comment: try to run this command ```flutter config --no-enable-web```

Comment: And check if you use html/js related packages, like `universal_html`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this, I followed [this link](https://medium.com/better-programming/dont-panic-when-flutter-generates-a-bad-file-for-you-e5e314c2b01). The reason why I can't recreate the project easily is that the project has grown so much that it would be a big hassle to move it into another project. This happened after we updated all of our libraries to their latest versions respectively.

FirestoreWeb caused our project to stop compiling but since we aren't using Flutter web and we don't plan to use it for this project, it wouldn't make sense for us to implement it.

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/64965377/2) to the question [Remove Web Part from Existing Flutter Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64965377/remove-web-part-from-existing-flutter-project) by the OP [kobowo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3649894/kobowo) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>